# How to mock a @ViewChild MatTabGroup in jest?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to test a new piece of code I added to my project. It allows users to select a tab on a page and when they refresh, the page is loaded on the same tab. I'm using localstorage to do this.

The issue I'm having is in the tests where it cannot set `selectedIndex` of `undefined`.

In the html on the mat-tab I have an event handler (`selectedTabChange`):

```
<mat-tab-group
  [selectedIndex]="selectedTab.value"
  (selectedIndexChange)="selectedTab.setValue($event)"
  (selectedTabChange)="handleMatTabChange($event)"
>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
    <div *ngIf="selectedTab.value === 0"> ... </div>
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
    <div *ngIf="selectedTab.value === 1"> ... </div>
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab label="Tab 3">
    <div *ngIf="selectedTab.value === 2"> ... </div>
  </mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

In the component I have

```
@ViewChild(MatTabGroup) tabGroup: MatTabGroup;


ngAfterViewInit() {
  const index = Number(localStorage.getItem('userTabLocation')) || 0;
  this.tabGroup.selectedIndex = index;
}

handleMatTabChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
  localStorage.setItem('userTabLocation', String(event.index));
}
```

Tests:

Checking if ViewChild is defined but it's `undefined`.

```
it('Should have `ViewChild` variable defined', () => {
  expect(component.tabGroup).toBeDefined();
});
```

Also in some of my other tests I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'selectedIndex' of undefined

   99 |   }
  100 | 
> 101 |   ngAfterViewInit() {
      |   ^
  102 |     const index = Number(localStorage.getItem('userTabLocation')) || 0;
  103 |     this.tabGroup.selectedIndex = index;
```

Things I have tried:

1. I read this really helpful article https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-unit-testing-viewchild-4525e0c7b756
2. Since my view child is a MatTabGroup, I've no idea how to stub that so the above article didn't help much. I tried this but that broke even more tests:

   ```
   component.tabGroup = TestBed.createComponent(MatTabGroup).componentInstance as MatTabGroup;
   ```
3. I have added the MatTabGroup into the providers like so, which didn't help:

   ```
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports: [ ... ],
         declarations: [ ... ],
         providers: [
         {
            provide: MatTabGroup,
         }],
   }).compileComponents();
   ```
4. I have added the useValues into the providers with the matTabGroup like so, which also didn't help:

   ```
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports: [ ... ],
         declarations: [ ... ],
         providers: [
         {
            provide: MatTabGroup,
            useValues: {
               selectedIndex: 0,
            }
         }],
   }).compileComponents();
   ```
5. I have added the `MatTabsModule` into the imports, also no luck:

   ```
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports: [ MatTabsModule ],
         declarations: [ ... ],
   }).compileComponents();
   ```

   But that gives the following error:

   ```
   Template parse errors:
   More than one component matched on this element.
   Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
   Conflicting components: MatTab,MatTab ("
   ```

   (EDIT): This was happening because I was importing `MaterialModule` too.

Any ideas? Really stuck on this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using Jasmine and Karma, `tabGroup` won't be defined until the ngAfterViewInit hook - I would assume you'll need to do a `fixture.detectChanges()` and then wait for `fixture.whenStable()` promise to return before it will be set in the test environment.  With Jest, you'll need to do whatever the equivalent is in that environment.